# Updating JSON to work with react-jsonschema-form format

Tags: javascript, json

I am working with react-jsonschema-form, I encountered a case to which requires the JSON to be updated but i am unable to recursively update the JSON according to the required format.

Given is this JSON:

```
{
  "Coordinates": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Coordinates",
    "properties": {
      "X-Coordinate": {
        "type": "number",
        "title": "X-Coordinate",
        "default": 47
      },
      "Y-Coordinate": {
        "type": "number",
        "title": "Y-Coordinate",
        "default": -122
      }
    }
  },
  "Coordination Type": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Coordination Type",
    "properties": {
      "Cartesion Mode": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "title": "Cartesion Mode",
        "default": false
      },
      "Starting Range": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Start Range",
        "properties": {
          "Start": {
            "type": "number",
            "title": "Start",
            "default": 8000
          },
          "End": {
            "type": "number",
            "title": "End",
            "default": 9000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "MapType": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Type Of Map",
      "default": "2D",
      "enum": [
          "2D",
          "3D"
      ]
  },
  "Map": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Map",
    "properties": {
      "Offline Map": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "title": "Offline Map",
        "default": false
      },
      "URL": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "URL",
        "default": "http://localhost:9000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want output as:

```
{
  "Coordinates": {
    "X-Coordinate": 47,
    "Y-Coordinate": -122
  },
  "Coordination Type": {
    "Cartesion Mode": false,
    "Starting Range": {
      "Start": 8000,
      "End": 9000
    }
  },
  "Type Of Map": "2D",
  "Map": {
    "Offline Map": false,
    "URL": "http://localhost:9000"
  }
}
```

I am able to achieve this using iterative format but that is not scalable. And i have been stuck for hours to get this in recursive method.
I would really appreciate if i get a recursive method to update this given JSON to the required format in `javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) can be used to modify nested values :

```js
var json = '{"Coordinates":{"type":"object","title":"Coordinates","properties":{"X-Coordinate":{"type":"number","title":"X-Coordinate","default":47},"Y-Coordinate":{"type":"number","title":"Y-Coordinate","default":-122}}},"Coordination Type":{"type":"object","title":"Coordination Type","properties":{"Cartesion Mode":{"type":"boolean","title":"Cartesion Mode","default":false},"Starting Range":{"type":"object","title":"Start Range","properties":{"Start":{"type":"number","title":"Start","default":8000},"End":{"type":"number","title":"End","default":9000}}}}},"MapType":{"type":"string","title":"Type Of Map","default":"2D","enum":["2D","3D"]},"Map":{"type":"object","title":"Map","properties":{"Offline Map":{"type":"boolean","title":"Offline Map","default":false},"URL":{"type":"string","title":"URL","default":"http://localhost:9000"}}}}'

var obj = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v.type ? v.properties || v.default : v)

console.log( obj )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, This solved my issue nicely.